# how to configure Camel transport for CXF with Blueprint

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint, camel-cxf

The Documentation of Camel transport for CXF with blueprint 
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/cxf-transport.html
says, the configuration looks like:

client: 
`<camel:conduit id="*.camel-conduit" camelContextId="camel1" />`

server: 
`<camel:destination id="*.camel-destination" camelContextId="camel1" />`

But Blueprint complaints: `'*.camel-destination' is not a valid value for 'NCname'`. Same for `'*.camel-conduit'` .

If I leave out the `id` attribute, the CXF client or CXF server starts up.
But when called, it doesn't find the Camel context.

CXF client:
org.apache.camel.component.cxf.transport.CamelConduit says 
IllegalAgumentException `"CamelContext must be specified on: conduit:"`

CXF server:
org.apache.camel.component.cxf.transport.CamelDestination says 
`IllegalAgumentException "CamelContext must be specified on:"`

Running on Fuse 6.3.

Does anybody know how I must configure CXF transport for Camel in Blueprint?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `"name"` attribute instead of the `"id"` one. 
It seems the documentation page(https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/cxf-transport.html) indicates that both the attributes can be used by I think that `"name"` is the correct one.

Comment: That was my first idea as well, since "name" is used for Spring DM. But: Attribute 'name' is not allowed to appear in element 'conduit'

Comment: Also, specifiyng a full `"QName.camel-conduit"`  in favour of `"*.camel-conduit"` is also not working, as this is no valid NCname as well.